# Unable to create chain pagination of MySQL database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

Thanks for your time. I am trying to build a freelance website. Currently, I am building my admin control panel. But to show user and freelancer data I want to use pagination in my user database page. But I am unable to implement the chain pagination with a number like page1, page2, page3, page4 .....,

I just added first, prev, next, last pagination button. Now I want to implement page number 1,2,3, 4,5 between the next and last button.. Please review my code, you will get what I want to do..

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Pagination</title>
      <!-- Bootstrap CDN -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <?php
         if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
             $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
         } else {
             $pageno = 1;
         }
         $no_of_records_per_page = 5;
         $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
         
         $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","blog_sample");
         // Check connection
         if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
             die();
         }
         
         $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_contact";
         $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
         $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
         $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
         
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_contact LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page";
         $res_data = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){
             echo "<table border='1'> 
         <tr>
         <th>Firstname</th>
         <th>Lastname</th>
         <th>Address</th>
         <th>Email</th>
         <th>Phone</th>
         <th>Date of Birth</th>
         
         </tr>";
         
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data))
         {
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['date_of_birth'] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
         }
         echo "</table>";
         }
         mysqli_close($conn);
         
         ?>
      <ul class="pagination">
         <li><a href="?pageno=1">First</a></li>
         <li class="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno <= 1){ echo ''; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno - 1); } ?>">Prev</a>
         </li>
         <li class="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo 'disabled'; } ?>">
            <a href="<?php if($pageno >= $total_pages){ echo ''; } else { echo "?pageno=".($pageno + 1); } ?>">Next</a>
         </li>
         <?php $pages = 0; for ( $i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++ ) {
            echo $pages += $i;
            //result 123456 , as total 6 pages exists.
            //but I want to implement the number in a list link, like this: <li><a hre="?pageno=1"</a></li>
            //<li><a hre="?pageno=2"</a></li>
            //<li><a hre="?pageno=3"</a></li>
            //<li><a hre="?pageno=4"</a></li>
            //<li><a hre="?pageno=5"</a></li>
            //<li><a hre="?pageno=blah-blah"</a></li>
            }?>
         <li><a href="?pageno=<?php echo $total_pages; ?>">Last</a></li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Just a heads-up for using pagination with a `limit` and `offset` clauses - you might wish to digest the information provided at http://allyouneedisbackend.com/blog/2017/09/24/the-sql-i-love-part-1-scanning-large-table/ if you will deal with large recordsets

Comment: you have nested loops both processing the same recordset...`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_data)){` ~ this occurs twice!

Comment: Your programming style is rather inconsistent. You start with HTML, then PHP which echoes HTML, and finally HTML with pieces of PHP in it. That is very uncomfortable for the reader. Your code looks cobbled together. Much can be improved here. It will give you less bugs, and make the code itself easier to write.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, How can I improve my code. Can you give me some suggestion bro? I'm a beginner in programming thats why I can not implement code properly..!

Comment: I understand. There are many PHP style guides out there, here is [a simple one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_coding_standard). Note how you haven't even used one function to structure your code? Use them! A useful function for your chain would, for instance, be `function chainLink($title, $url)`. A resource with endless good advice is: [PHP The Right Way](https://phptherightway.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment I made previously It appears that your table does not have an `auto-increment` column / Primary key. Whilst not essential it would allow for more efficient table operations such as editing , deleting and, in this case, recordset pagination. Given that there are not many records the benefits of using an ID based pagination system over the limit/offset technique used here would be minimal ( if indeed even noticeable )

Also, in the originally posted code there are two loops ( nested ) trying to process the same recordset which, at best, would produce a weird & incorrect HTML structure and at worst consume loads of resources. I suspect this was a mistake and not the intention.

The piece of work you mentioned is hopefully achieved towards the end ( see comments )

```
<?php

    $pageno=!empty( $_GET['pageno'] ) ? filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'pageno', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT ) : 1;
    $rpp = 5;

    $offset = ( $pageno - 1 ) * $rpp;

    $conn=mysqli_connect( "localhost", "root", "", "blog_sample" );

    $sql = "select count(*) as `totalrows` from `tbl_contact`";
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );


    $rs = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQLI_ASSOC );
    $total_pages = ceil( $rs['totalrows'] / $rpp );

    $sql = "select * from `tbl_contact` limit $offset, $rpp";
    $results = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );


    /* generate table and headers */
        echo "
        <table border='1'> 
            <tr>
                 <th>Firstname</th>
                 <th>Lastname</th>
                 <th>Address</th>
                 <th>Email</th>
                 <th>Phone</th>
                 <th>Date of Birth</th>
            </tr>";

    /* now process recrodset */ 
    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $results ) ){
        echo "
            <tr>
                 <td>{$row['first_name']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['last_name']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['address']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['phone']}</td>
                 <td>{$row['date_of_birth']}</td>
            </tr>";
    }

    echo "
    </table>";

    mysqli_close( $conn );



    /* generate appropriate links for current pageno */
    $first = $pageno > 0 ? sprintf('<a href="?pageno=%d">First</a>', 1 ) : '<span>First</span>';
    $last  = $pageno < $total_pages ? sprintf('<a href="?pageno=%d">Last</a>', $total_pages ) : '<span>Last</span>';
    $next = $pageno < $total_pages - 1 ? sprintf('<a href="?pageno=%d">Next</a>', $pageno + 1 ) : '<span>Next</span>';
    $prev = $pageno > 1 ? sprintf('<a href="?pageno=%d">Previous</a>', $pageno - 1 ) : '<span>Previous</span>';


    /* generate the additional links for ALL pages */
    $html=[];
    for( $i=0; $i < $total_pages; $i++ ){
        $page=$i+1;
        $html[]=sprintf('<li><a class="int-pag-nav" href="?pageno=%d">%d</a></li>', $page, $page );
    }


    /* print the list and add ALL links between next and last */
    printf("
        <ul class='pagination'>
            <li>%s</li>
            <li>%s</li>
            <li>%s</li>
            %s
            <li>%s</li>
        </ul>",
        $first, 
        $prev, 
        $next, 
        implode( PHP_EOL, $html ), 
        $last
    );

?>
```

When used with the following CSS it produces a display similar to the following image:

```
<style>
    .pagination{list-style:none}
    .pagination li{min-width:1rem; height:1rem;border:1px solid rgba(100,100,100,0.25);padding:0.5rem; display:inline-block;clear:none;text-align:center}
    .pagination a{color:blue;}
    .pagination a.int-pag-nav{color:red}
</style>
```

The resultant image
[image: Pagination links with ALL pages listed between next and last]

Comment: Thank you sir, for your effort! But some problem arose.. At the top of the page I am getting a warning as follows: "Warning: Illegal string offset 'totalrows' in C:\xampp\htdocs\pageno.php on line 24". The database is working, showing 5 rows per page. But after the database,I' getting another error, Warning: sprintf(): Too few arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\pageno.php on line 72.

And any pagination button is not working. and also I'm not getting the chain number pagination link means "implode( PHP_EOL, $html ), " code is not working. 

Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that - just made two changes which should(hopefully) correct those problems. I'm not sure I understand the last comment regarding `I'm not getting the chain number pagination link means "implode( PHP_EOL, $html ), " code is not working. ` ~ please advise if this issue remains after changes

Comment: Glad to help - consider accepting the answer or voting if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code  sample code this also dynamically pagination

```
<?php
// Database have two Columns id and email
require_once 'profile/include/data_base.php';
$limit=5; // How many Number of record will fetch at one page
$link="http://$server_name/rishi/pagination1.php";
?>
<!-- HTML Parts-->
<html>
 <head> <title>Pagination Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <center>Pagination Example in PHP</center>
   <?php
    if(isset($_GET["page_id"])){
        $page_id=$_GET["page_id"];
    }
    else{
      // By Default First Page will Display
        $page_id=1; 
    }


// From Starting Content on Page
$from_page=($page_id-1) * $limit;

// To get the Total Number of Columns in Table
$total_data=$con->query("select * from r_register");

//Total numbers of Tabs that will display below
$total_tabs=ceil($total_data->num_rows/$limit);

$all_data=$con->query("select * from r_register LIMIT ".$from_page.",".$limit);
if($all_data->num_rows > 0)
    {
        while($row=$all_data->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row["id"] ." ".$row["email"]."<br>";
    }
}


?>

<div class="pagination">
  <?php
  $num=1;
   // To take Previous Page or to display '<'
  if($page_id >1)
  {
    $minus_one=$page_id-1;
     echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$minus_one.'" class="a_link ">&lt</a>';
  }
  // Starting two page number will always be there.
if($page_id >1){
 echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id=1" class="a_link">1</a>'; 
}
if($page_id >2){
 echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id=2" class="a_link">2</a>'; 
}
// .. will Display
if($page_id >4)
{
  echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.($page_id-2).'" class="a_link">..</a>';
}

// One  Previous  From Current Page
if($page_id >3){
    $current_preivous=$page_id-1;

    echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$current_preivous.'" class="a_link">'.$current_preivous.'</a>';  
}


    while($num <=$total_tabs){
       if($page_id == $num){
      // To make css Change On Current page
        echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$num.'" class="a_link a_active">'.$num.'</a>';
       }
        $num++;
     }



if($total_tabs-$page_id >=3)
{
  // Next Page from Current Page
    $current_next=$page_id+1;
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$current_next.'" class="a_link">'.$current_next.'</a>';
}

//one Previous constant value

    if($page_id<$total_tabs-3)
     {
      $preious_end=$total_tabs-2;
      echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$preious_end.'"class="a_link">..</a>';
     }

     if($page_id<$total_tabs-1)
     {
        $preious_end=$total_tabs-1;
        echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$preious_end.'" class="a_link">'.$preious_end.'</a>';
     }

     if($page_id < $total_tabs){
     echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$total_tabs.'" class="a_link">'.$total_tabs.'</a>';
     }


  //To Display '>'
     if($page_id < $total_tabs)
  {
    $plus_one=$page_id+1;
    echo '<a href="'.$link.'?page_id='.$plus_one.'" class="a_link">&gt</a>';
  }
 ?>
</div>
 </body>

 <style>
 .pagination{
    background-color: #039a9a;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
 }
 .a_link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    padding: 5px;
 }
 .a_active{
    color: white;
 }
 </style>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks sir but where is pagination1.php and data_base.php?

Comment: current page is only pagination1.php and in data_base.php it will only have the mysqli connection

Comment: You can change the page name as you'r desire at the vairable  $link so that you can use the pagination on the current page with $_GET method and you can also set the no. of records per page with $limit vairable

Comment: Thank your sir! I got it

Comment: Thats great that you got it. upvote the answer if you think it is helpful to other